# XSD/Schema validation workaround in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, xsd-validation

I got from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3633, that XSD Schema Validation now is not yet supported, and planned in `.Net Core 1.2.0` whose release date is Spring, 2017.

However it's one of the key features of our product, so it somehow has to be supported. Now .Net Standard doesn't even have `System.Xml.Schema` when we thought to temporarily use full .net core, yet doesn't help.

Before `v1.2.0`, is there any workaround to do the xsd schema validation?

Answer (score 0):

If you need some functionality that needs to be run in `.Net Core` library, you may try to port your product with [`portable` library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/libraries) workaround.

However, it's nearly the [`.NET Core 2.0 Preview`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) time, so you may basically wait for it.