# Is there a way to generate xml schema (xsd) in .net core runtime?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, metadata, .net-core

I have an issue to publish xml schemas (`.xsd`) for the some types with `.Net Core`. It should be runtime and cross-platform. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40379881/213550

Answer (score 1):

According the [`.NET Core Roadmap`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) and team member comment [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3633#issuecomment-261299151), this is planned to be a part of .Net Core `1.2` release on Q2 2017.